# How do I correctly implement toolbars inside fragments in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar in my `TimelineFragment` which I recently added. And there is an already existing collapsing toolbar which previously worked fine in my `ProfileFragment` until when I added the similar toolbar to the `TimelineFragment`. Both of these fragments are contained in a view pager.

I have the ff layout for the `ProfileFragment`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivProfileAvatar"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/divider_small"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_image" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="JuanOne"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_header"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserCommunity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="University Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserBio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Still learning to face difficulty"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_content" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEditProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient_blue"
                android:paddingStart="48dp"
                android:paddingEnd="48dp"
                android:text="Edit Profile"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <!--
                DO NOT CHANGE,
                CHANGE ONLY IF TOOLBAR SIZE (FOR TAB_LAYOUT) IS ALSO CHANGED
             -->
            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabsProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:tabBackground="@null"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/tabProfileMySSSS"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/tabProfileMySSSSS"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ibtnProfileTimelineRefresh"
                    android:layout_width="128dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/divider_normal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_autorenew_white_24dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

which is inside a `CoordinatorLayout`

and the ff layout for the `TimelineFragment`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cvCreateSSSSS"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/divider_small"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/divider_small"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/divider_normal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="32dp"
                            android:layout_height="32dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/svg_nav_create_SSSSSS" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/divider_normal"
                            android:text="What's on your mind?"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_content" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="32dp"
                            android:layout_height="32dp"
                            android:padding="@dimen/divider_xsmall"
                            android:src="@drawable/svg_insert_image" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:visibility="gone">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <...some other layouts />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For visuals on what my issue is

** This image is from the `ProfileFragment`

[image]

The extra space which I marked red has not existed before, when I still haven't added the `AppBarLayout` (containing the toolbar) on the `TimelineFragment`.

I have tried removing the whole `AppBarLayout` on the `TimelineFragment`, and it does fix the weird extra space on the `ProfileFragment`. Why is it that there is a relation between these fragments when they do not share anything besides being in the same `ViewPager`?

How do I remove the space that I marked red on the image? It might be related to the toolbar since it is same in color. The `AppBarLayout` uses a lighter color than the toolbar.

Comment: you are using
android:layout_marginTop="92dp" in your CoordinatorLayout tag
remove this and check

Comment: and also you can use these propertiees in Coordinator layout:
android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Answer (score 0):

I have already fixed it. Apparently, the Activity that was holding all these fragments is using coordinator layout. So I removed that, and that space was gone. I believe that using a toolbar inside these fragments made the activity holding them create a toolbar on its own.